# Grib to netcdf with 4 dimensions and multiple variables

Tags: cmd, netcdf, grib

I am trying to convert a grib file into netcdf with wgrib2. I am working on Windows 10. My grib file has 4 dimensions and 2 variables:

[image: grib file]

My two variables are Temperature and Total precipitation rate with the following dimensions : time (length 20), ens (length 50), lat (length 27) and lon (length 21).

I tried to use wgrib with the following line command :

```
wgrib2.exe MyFile.grib -netcdf Output.nc
```

A netcdf file is written but with only three dimensions for the two variables (time, lat, lon), so the 'ens' variable is dropped. I saw in the documentation that wgrib2 mainly managed 3D.

So I want to extract 50 files from my grib file, 1 for each ensemble member, and then convert these 50 files into netcdf files. I will then create a merged netcdf file thanks to R. For this I tried the following command line :

```
wgrib2.exe MyFile.grib -match ':ens=1:' -grib Output_1.grib
```

Then I wanted to do :

```
wgrib2.exe Output_1.grib -netcdf Output_1.nc
```

But the extraction of ens=1 does not work, a file is written but its weight is 0Ko. The only command that works is :

```
wgrib2.exe MyFile.grib -if ':ens=1:' > Output_1.grib
```

It creates a 24Ko file but then I try to open it or to convert it into netcdf, it does not work. I opened it with notepad and it gives a two column file with numbers...

Can someone help me to extract my variables for each ensemble member (ens)  ?
I can't use cdo as I can't install cygwin, I am very limited for installing programs (company context).

Thanks

Comment: Last year, the ECMWF published a python package called "cfgrib". It is based on eccodes and xarray. You will need 10 lines of code to do what you want. cfgrib is really great software. https://github.com/ecmwf/cfgrib

Comment: Thanks for the trick, I finally used Linux and cdo with my personal computer... so limited on Windows...